# JS Promise doesn't chain while working chrome.storage.sync

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, chaining

I'm trying to make a promise chaining, but somehow the asynchronous calling using `chrome.storage.sync.get` always return later. Here's a correct order I thought it should be:

1. Create an element and append to body
2. Call `chrome.storage.sync`
3. Based on 2) result, trigger some event on element created in 1)

I've already tried to put new Promise in 2) step, but no successful.
The `console.log` always return in a wrong order. Something like:

1. // insertChecbox done
2. // start promise chrome.storage.sync
3. // undefined
4. // result asnyc: ...

Here's my attempt:

```
const pr = new Promise(resolve => {
  this.createCheckbox();
  console.log('insertChecbox done')
  resolve();
});

pr
  .then( resolve => {
    console.log("start promise chrome.storage.sync");

    return new Promise( resolve => {
      return resolve(chrome.storage.sync.get(["code", "isAutocheck"], result => {
        console.log('result async: ', result );
        return result
      }));
    });
  })
  .then( result => {
    console.log(result);
    console.log('This always run before the `chrome.storage.sync` finishes loading`)
    if (result.isAutocheck) {
      const domCheckbox = this.getCheckboxElement();
      domCheckbox && domCheckbox.click();
    }
  });
```

I wanted to separate the result of `chrome.storage.sync` because I need to  work on other stuff, not making this callback too complex

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for noticing this question, I've found an solution by changing a bit in my first `.then`, by explicitly resolving the result of `chrome.storage.sync.get`, not the whole thing.

```
pr
  .then( () => {
    return new Promise( resolve => {
      return chrome.storage.sync.get(["code", "isAutocheck"], result => {
        console.log('result async: ', result );
        return resolve(result)
      });
    });
  })
  .then(...);
```